# Best strategy for server side DB Writes

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a server which makes many writes to a database for clients connected to it. The more connections to it the more writing its doing. My question is.. How can I handle this most elegantly? As the DB gets bigger inserts/updates are taking longer and longer which in turn lags the clients as responses from server are getting increasingly slower.

One of the things I have thought about is having a DB Helper program which I write to a QUEUE database and as a separate application it will write as it is allocated. This would allow the server to stay more focused but I'm not sure if this is the best route.

Any help would be great.

```
<Debug> -- 10/6/2012 8:57:15 PM -- UPDATE mapdata SET X = @1, Y = @2, Rank = @3, Health = @4, Beacons = @20,Armors = @5, Duals = @6, Missiles = @7, Homings = @8, Radars = @9, HasRankKill = @10, TotalPP = @11, RankPP = @12, KillCount = @13, DeathCount = @14, TimePlayed = @15, EnabledEquipment = @16 WHERE MapID = @17 AND TankID = @18 AND Color = @19;
<Debug> -- 10/6/2012 8:57:15 PM -- Time to execute: 00:00:00.0468003
```

This is taking half a second to execute.

I have indexes on MapData as follows:

```
PRIMARY: MapID, TankID, Color
MapID: MapID
TankID: TankID

'MapData', 'CREATE TABLE `mapdata` (\n  `MapID` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `TankID` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `Color` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,\n  `X` int(11) DEFAULT \'-1\',\n  `Y` int(11) DEFAULT \'-1\',\n  `Rank` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `Health` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'1200\',\n  `Armors` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `Duals` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `Missiles` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `Homings` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `Radars` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `Beacons` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `HasRankKill` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b\'0\',\n  `TotalPP` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `RankPP` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `KillCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `DeathCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `TimePlayed` time NOT NULL DEFAULT \'00:00:00\',\n  `EnabledEquipment` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `Prestige` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  PRIMARY KEY (`MapID`,`TankID`,`Color`),\n  KEY `MapID` (`MapID`),\n  KEY `TankID` (`TankID`),\n  CONSTRAINT `mapdata_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MapID`) REFERENCES `maps` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,\n  CONSTRAINT `mapdata_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`TankID`) REFERENCES `tank` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Comment: I just want to clarify, so this is only writes, no reads?  Do you have any unneeded indexes?

Comment: I've updated the ticket, added some logging of the problem child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i have done this for a multiplayer game was to spawn a DBManager on a thread.

DBManager would be a singleton class with a static object called lock

This had a single public method "Enqueue" that would take raw SQL, or a specific game object to save to the DB (Tanks in this case)

When you enter enqueue you call Lock on your lock object above, and enqueue to your list of items needing saved to the DB and return so that the application can continue.

The thread would wake up every 30 seconds or so, process the queue and then go back to sleep.

The down side to this method is that you will have a potential for data loss, so you can lose the sleep/wake cycle to reduce the risk but obviously thats a bit more data/processor intensive.

Comment: Are you still working on this since 2012? The progressive slow down probably comes from many indexes in inserted table. Remove most of them. It is also good to migrate to MS SQL or other RDBMS.

Comment: no lol this is really old and i was just providing what ended up working for me. i have no idea why people are downvoting my own answer.

Comment: With downvote someone wants to say that solution is not good.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to keep the server from being bogged down is to use multi-threading.  This allows the server to continue responding to incoming requests while the threads handle the database updates.  I'm not sure if mysql is thread-safe, so you might have to implement a lock around the database.